# C++ Program That Determines if A Line In A File Contains An Arabic Or Roman Numeral

Tags: c++, file, filestream

Basically,I have an assignment in which I have to have a C++ program that will read a file and determine whether each line contains an Arabic Numeral or Roman Numeral, and then proceed to translate it to the other, like if the number was an Arabic numeral, it would be translated to a Roman and vice versa.

This is supposed to be done by a file in which the first 16 spaces of each line will contain the Roman numeral and the last 4 spaces are reserved for the arabic numerals, and when the program reads the first space fo a line as blank, it immediately skips 16 spaces and reads the number following it. The problem is: I can't seem to get my program to even recognize the space in front.

This is what I have so far, I haven't even gotten to the translating part because I've been so hung up on figuring out how I can get my program to recognize the space in front, skip 16 spaces, and then record the number in the back as an int.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
void arabicToRoman(string, int);
void RomantoArabic(string, int);
int main()
{
string number;
string ArabicNum;
string numeral;
int arabicNumber;
fstream myfile("numbers.txt", fstream::in);

while (getline(myfile, number))
{
  if (number.size() && number[1] == ' ')
  {
     getline(myfile, number, '\n');
     cout << "Arabic number is: "<<number << endl;
  }
  else
  {
     getline(myfile, numeral, '\n');
     cout << "Roman number is: " << number << endl;
  }

}





return 0;
}
```

also just in case here's the text file I've labeled here as "numbers.txt"

```
XIV                 
                2100
                3568
XXVI                
                420 
                6584
IIV                 
VII                 
IV                  
                360
```

Comment: The C family of languages use zero-based arrays, so the first element is `number[0]` not `number[1]`.

Comment: *I haven't even gotten to the translating part because I've been so hung up on figuring out how I can get my program to recognize the space in front* -- My opinion, but you fell into the trap that a lot of beginners get into, and that is wasting time on inputting and output formatting, and leave no time for what really counts, in your case, the translation from / to Arabic and Roman (which you should have done first).

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code:

```
fstream myfile("numbers.txt", fstream::in);

while (getline(myfile, number))
```

You don't check whether the file opened, you will simply never run the while loop if it didn't. Consider doing:

```
fstream myfile("numbers.txt");
if (!myfile.is_open()) {
    std::cerr << "couldn't open file\n";
    return 1;
}
```

Next

```
while (getline(myfile, number))  //#1
{
  if (number.size() && number[1] == ' ') //#2
  {
     getline(myfile, number, '\n'); //#3
```

On the first pass, #1 reads the first line of the file. It then, #2, compares the *second character* of the line with space - C++ uses zero-based arrays. You want `number[0]` or `number.front()`.

However, #3 now reads the *second* line of the file.

What you probably wanted here is:

```
while (std::getline(myfile, number))
{
  if (!number.size())
    continue;
  if (number.front() == ' ') {
     if (number.size() > 16)
       std::cout << "Arabic number is: " << number.substr(16) << std::endl;
  } else {
     std::cout << "Roman number is: " << number << std::endl;
  }
}
```